# Get table as auto argument when calling C function from the same table field

Tags: c, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I have several global integer variables, like A0, A1, A2 in Lua script. They are declared on C side. Each of them contains unique numeric value.
In a script user manipulates device pins using this aliases:

```
set_pin_bool(A0, 1)
```

And this calls corresponding C function. I think it is too C-like and not very handy. The better is to call methods like A0.hi(), A0.low(), A0.set(1) etc.
So I tried to declare A0 and others as tables in C(**this** is just a struct):

```
lua_newtable(this->luactx);     
lua_pushstring(this->luactx, "val");
lua_pushinteger(this->luactx, value);
lua_rawset(this->luactx, -3);
lua_setglobal ( this->luactx, "A0" );
```

I can create a filed like **hi** and using lua_pushcfunction register it. But when I call A0.hi(), on C side I won't be able to access a table it was called from to get another fields. And as I googled there is no way to get something like **self** from C. Is there any way to accomplish it? I don't want to pass table itself as argument, like **A0.hi(A0)**
There may be a lot of aliases and they can be named differently.
Or may be there are different approaches to the same goal?

Comment: What about just doing `A0:hi()`?

Comment: And what is the difference then? I'm sorry I'm quite new to Lua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your `hi` function like this:

```
A0:hi()
```

This is equivalent to:

```
A0.hi(A0)
```